# How to create more than one project in single Gitlab repository

Tags: git, gitlab

Currently we are using single repos for each project, like project/IOS, Project/Android, etc.. It creates many repos for the same project in GitLab. Are there any best practice to create single repos for multiple projects?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the bellow steps to create single repos for multiple projects

**Step 1 :** Instead of creating multiple Repos, Create Group with any specified name `Ex : Project`. In that create sub groups like `Ex. Project1 and Project2`, here both are subgroup of Project.

**Step 2 :** Create a new project called project/Android in group Project 1 and project/IOS in group project2

**Step 3 :** Add the user with permission like `developer` and `master` , in individual Sub groups .

**Step 4 :** Added user were inheritance the  permission from Parental groups

> Note : Doing this,  we can able to reduce the multiple Repos for the
>   Same project.

Answer (score 1):

You can [group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/) the projects. You'd still have multiple repos though.